# Find form $error length

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to get the number of errors in $scope.someForm.$error and can't figure out a way to get the count.

Example $error:

```
$scope.someForm.$error
Object{date-disabled: Array[1], required: Array[1]}
```

Expected Result is 2.

Is there a way to get the count of objects that resulted in an error?

I'm trying to do this because I ran into an issue with bootstraps date-picker invalidating my angular form.
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3439

Now I want to code around the issue with a check. I want to say $scope.someForm.$error count is 1 and is date-disabled continue with form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the object keys and total the array lengths:

```
var totalErrors = 0;
for (var error in $scope.someForm.$error) {
    if ($scope.someForm.$error.hasOwnProperty(error)) {
        totalErrors += $scope.someForm.$error[error].length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was almost there. I was hoping there was something in the form object that told me the error count.